# where should linux kernel modules install headers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kbuild

I have an out of tree linux kernel module that has a public header. This header is intended to be shared with other modules, as it declares exported functions of the module, and not with userspace.

- where should my module install this headers?
- that make target should be used for this?

I read about the Kbuild `header-y` variable but it does not seem to be in use in current kernel any more. There is the `header_install` and `headers_install_all` target. But this are intended to generate userspace api headers that are placed in `/usr/include`?
And finaly just placing the headers in normal includepath (e.g. `/usr/include`) would not work as this is not part of the normal kernel includepath during module build.

Comment: There isn't really a standard place to store out-of-tree kernel headers, but I would suggest installing them somewhere outside the usual userspace include paths. For the other modules, you can arrange for the extra `-I directory` options to be passed to the `ccflags-y` variable in their Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after weeks of search it seems that this is it. there is no predefined place for out of tree build module dependency headers.

my current solution is to add this on the modules that export headers:

```
INSTALL_MOD_PATH ?= /
INSTALL_HDR_PATH ?= $(INSTALL_MOD_PATH)/usr/include/
INSTALL_HDR_PATH_KERNEL ?= $(INSTALL_MOD_PATH)/usr/src/include/


header_install:
    install -d $(INSTALL_HDR_PATH)
    install -d $(INSTALL_HDR_PATH_KERNEL)
    install -Dm 0655 ./user.h $(INSTALL_HDR_PATH)/user.h
    install -Dm 0655 ./mod-external.h $(INSTALL_HDR_PATH_KERNEL)/mod-external.h
```

and in the dependen modules do this on build

```bash
export KCFLAGS="-I$(INSTALL_MOD_PATH)/usr/src/include/"
make
```

this promotes `/usr/src/include` to be the folder for header exchange